# Kafka Consumer Sending More Fetch Requests to Broker

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am having a Kafka Consumer which fetches the broker in a given fetch interval. It is fetching with the given time interval and it is fine when the messages are there in a topic. But i really don't know the reason why consumer is sending more fetch requests when there are no messages in kafka topic.

Answer (score 0):

In general, consumers send two types of requests to broker:

- Heartbeat
- Poll request

Heartbeat is sent via separate thread and its interval is configured with `heartbeat.interval.ms` (3 seconds in default)

For poll request there is no specific interval and it's up to your code. (there is just an upper bound for it (`max.poll.interval.ms`))

It is absolutely reasonable to send  more frequent poll requests when there is no data in partition(s) that your consumer is assigned to. Suppose that you have a code like this:

```
 void consumeLoop() {
    while (true) {
        records = consumer.poll();
        if(!records.isEmpty()) {
            processMessages(records);
        }
    }
}
```

As you see if there is no records returned from poll, then your consumer will immediately send another poll request. But if there is data, you should first process these records before sending next poll request.